# Where is the time-zones.rd file been moved to?

Tags: r, posixct

I'm interested in converting datetimes for multiple time zones. In as.POSIX* help (a base function), under argument it says,

> tz
>   time zone specification to be used for the conversion, if one is required. System-specific (see time zones), but "" is the current time zone, and "GMT" is UTC (Universal Time, Coordinated). Invalid values are most commonly treated as UTC, on some platforms with a warning.

The time zones help link is to http://127.0.0.1:31155/help/library/base/help/time%20zones and is broken.

Comment: (1) the `127.0.0.1:31155` is a local-only link that (I believe) changes ports with each R session, so you cannot expect it to persist in the long term; (2) I found the info as `?timezones` (no hyphen); (3) https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/timezones.html

Comment: @r2evans that's helpful!